# Visual Studio 2022 New Class Code Template Using File Scoped Namespace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I want VS to generate new classes using the new way of declaring namespaces, ie:

```
namespace A.Namespace.For.Class;
public class ANewClass
{
}
```

But my VS2022 still uses the old way, ie:

```
namespace A.Namespace.For.Class
{
    public class ANewClass
    {
    }
}
```

So I tried to change the template file located at
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs`

I changed it to the below:

```
namespace $rootnamespace$;
public class $safeitemrootname$
{
}
```

But it looks like VS2022 can't interpret the semicolon after the namespace's name because it still uses the old style. But as soon as I remove the semicolon, VS starts to use the new style except that I now have to manually add that semicolon myself.

Anyone knows how to escape that semicolon in that code template file? No documentation seems to be available.

Comment: isn't it depends on the setting in the project file?

Comment: @T.S. Maybe you can give me some more details on it? We have 20 projects so didn't look into project settings.

Comment: Never mind. I was thinking about `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>` . I've never seen `using { namespace{..} }`

Comment: @T.S. Sorry my bad. I am updating my code snippets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to change the template, this is configurable, go to

`Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > General`

In `Code block preferences` section, change `Namespace declarations` to `File scoped`.

Comment: Fantastic. That saves my life. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [@shingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6196568/shingo) is the best, I think, but it is worth mentioning, that you can achieve the same by modifying the template (as you did) plus disable the auto formatting (back to block-scoped namespace) in the `.editorconfig` file. (Source: https://blog.jdriven.com/2022/12/changing_visual_studio_cs_templates/)

```
[*.cs]
csharp_style_namespace_declarations=file_scoped:suggestion
```